# In-memory log buffer size in BerkeleyDB-Core-JAVA

Tags: java, berkeley-db

I'm using in-memory log buffer in Berkeley BerkeleyDB-Core-JAVA edition.
I have CDRFile of 9 lack records.
When I am writing  CDRFile in database in durable database environment(i.e log files are created)  then total 1.08gb of log files are created and when I am setting this two parameters of in memory log buffer:

```
envconfig.setLogInMemory(true);
envconfig.setLogBufferSize(1181116006); // 1.10 gb
```

i m getting error like:

```
-------------------------error----------------
PANIC: Not enough space
PANIC: DB_RUNRECOVERY: Fatal error, run database recovery
unable to join the environment
DataBase Exceptioncom.sleepycat.db.RunRecoveryException: DB_RUNRECOVERY: Fatal error,
run database recovery: PANIC: DB_RUNRECOVERY: Fatal error, run database recovery
unable to join the environment: DB_RUNRECOVERY: Fatal error, run database recovery
Writing DataBase Exception--->java.lang.NullPointerException
 ------------------------------error----------------------
```

so I think if  1 gb log of files are created on disk then I must set 1gb of space  in buffer memory also for log files.

Answer (score 0):

this kind of question can usually be answered more quickly on the Berkeley DB [forum](http://bit.ly/eIREhr) for Berkeley DB core or the Berkeley DB Java Edition [forum](http://bit.ly/e1AYFi) for BDB JE on OTN.

Based on your error message, it looks like you're using Berkeley DB (core) via the Java API. My guess is that you're running out of log buffer space. In Berkeley DB the default size for an in-memory log buffer is 1MB. You can either extend the log buffer to be larger by calling [DB_ENV->set_lg_bsize()](http://bit.ly/qyNzEZ) in C or [setlogBufferSize](http://bit.ly/og9gHF) in Java. Otherwise, you can break up the transaction into smaller chunks so that you don't exceed the size of the log buffer in a single transaction.

Do you experience this problem when you don't create the log file in-memory, if you use a smaller transaction or if you allocated a larger in-memory log buffer?

I hope that this helps.

Regards,

Dave